# IIS Redirect from subfolder to different domain

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config, plesk

I am facing the following problem:

I need to redirect all enquiries at

**domain-1.com/umbraco**

to

**subdomain.domain-2.com/umbraco**

---

I am hosting the website using plesk. In plesk I have

**domain-1.com** as the main Domain

and

**subdomain.domain-2.com** set up as an alias for domain-1.com

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to redirect in plesk or iis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global.asax` and create a redirect there on each request as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://domain-1.com/umbraco"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://subdomain.domain-2.com/" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Path, false);            
    }    
}
```